# Flutter Rate Limit / Debouncer Design Implementation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a small application for a friend who is trying to buy shoes that sell out frequently, and this application uses a web scraper to load a website and check a portion of its content as a status check every once in a while (don't want to hit this very frequently).

The issue I'm noticing, is that all of this action is being done during the build phase of the widget. As you can probably see, this isn't a good option. When I am re-sizing the application on desktop, the build method is called rapidly many times, which causes many many calls to be made to scrape the website which is undesired.

Here's a look at the code as it stands:

```dart
  //should be moved into a controller I think
  //Or at least somewhere to 'debounce' the web scraping during each rebuild
  Stream<bool?> productChecker(Duration minInterval, Duration maxInterval) async* {
    assert(maxInterval > minInterval);

    //begin checking continuously
    do {
      //signal that we're checking again
      yield null;
      //construct duration to wait between calls
      Duration waitTime = minInterval + Duration(milliseconds: math.Random().nextInt((maxInterval - minInterval).inMilliseconds));
      bool loaded = await scraper.loadWebPage(unencodedPath);
      bool isInStock = false;
      if(loaded){
        final inStockElements = scraper.getElement(cartButtonId, []);
        assert(inStockElements.isNotEmpty);
        final inStockElement = inStockElements[0];
        isInStock = inStockElement['title'] != cartButtonInStockContent;
        print('In Stock: $isInStock');
      }
      yield loaded ? isInStock : false;
      print('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}: Waiting for ${waitTime.inSeconds} seconds');
      await Future.delayed(waitTime);
    }while(true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: productChecker(5.seconds, 30.seconds),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool?> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return snapshot.data != null ?
          snapshot.data! ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => launch(baseUrl+unencodedPath), child: 'In Stock'.text.make()) :
          'Out of Stock'.text.make() :
          CircularProgressIndicator();
        }else{
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

So my question is this:

***How should I implement a controller that will keep track of the last time the website was scraped, and a cool down duration that will ignore scrape requests during the cool down?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a broad answer but for reactive frameworks like flutter you really want to separate the business logic from the view logic. Your issue is that your business logic is in the build function which is purely for view logic. I am not to familiar with StreamBuilder but I think you could utilize a plain build function inside a stateful widget to achieve what you want.

A widget would have your scraper in the `initState()`/`dispose()` functions. Set some values up that will contain the info needed for your view then your build will contain 3 displays based on the state of isInStock.
**Remember when you change isInStock to use the function*
`setState(() { isInStock = true; });`
setState ensures that after updating the state that the view rebuilds.

- if null then that means the scraper is still awaiting data, show
  loading view
- if true then show your launch button
- if false then show out of stock text

Rebuilds will not trigger business logic because it is outside of the build so now all you need to do is worry about the business logic and the view will then reflect what the outcome of it is.